# Re-render the React table after CRUD Operations

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am performing an updation using a react table and redux store. Although all the API calls are fired properly, the changes are not shown in the React table until refreshing the page. I am handling the update method in the component as follows.

```
handleEdit = () => {
    this.props.editCard({
      id: this.state.id,
      createdAt: this.state.createdAt,
      name: this.state.name,
      uid: this.state.uid,
      serial: this.state.serial,
      name: this.state.name,
      status: this.state.status,
      nodeType: this.state.nodeType
    });

  };
```

Can someone help me for solving this matter?

Comment: Also post your `editCard` method code.

Comment: Take the code of ComponentDidMount and put it inside a function , And then call the function inside handleEdit() at the bottom